# Trying to load a .mp4 Video fails using open CV

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg, video-capture

I've installed ffmpeg and opencv on my linux server, like that:

```
git clone <ffmpeg_git_repositiory>
cd FFmpeg
./configure --enable-shared
make
sudo make install

sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev

git clone <opencv_git_repositiory>
cmake <path to="" the="" opencv="" source="" directory="">
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make
sudo make install
```

I wrote a little Python script:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
```

But I'm not able to load that video and total_frames are always 0.

I did some research why this doesn't work and found tons of answers tried so many ways to install it, but it didn't work for me.

What did I do wrong? Am I missing some detail?

I'm really annoyed and from installing it

**EDIT:**

When `cmake` opencv, it shows me this:

```
--   Video I/O:                                                              
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO                                       
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)                          
--     FFMPEG:                      YES                                      
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.80.101)                      
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.66.102)                      
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.47.100)                      
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.3.101)                        
--       avresample:                YES (ver 1.0.1)                          
--     GStreamer:                   NO                                       
--     OpenNI:                      NO                                       
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO                                       
--     OpenNI2:                     NO                                       
--     PvAPI:                       NO                                       
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO                                       
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO                                       
--     UniCap:                      NO                                       
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO                                       
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES                                   
--     XIMEA:                       NO                                       
--     Xine:                        NO                                       
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
```

So ffmpeg should be usable, right?

**EDIT 2:**

After reinstall on a fresh new VM I get this error:

```
[mp3 @ 0x1dbb2a0] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x1dbb2a0] Header missing
Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device
(python:17171): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Why did you compile and install FFmpeg (which will provide the cli tools and libav* libraries) and then install `libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev` from the repo?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard while installation there were no critical errors which mentioned ffmpeg (just some deprecations and non-critical warnings)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard So also edit

Comment: *See And concerning your question. I'm not completely sure what and why I did it. I just tried so many different things because the proposed way didn't work for me...

Comment: As for errors, I meant from your script, not from the ffmpeg compilation.

Comment: No there were no errors. 
I simply can't load the video :/

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I reinstalled everything on a completely new VM using this script: https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV
And I got the errors in the EDIT

Comment: GLib relater errors sounds like it is depending on GStreamer. Did you try to install GStreamer dependencies? I think OpenCV is using GStreamer to load files and acces cameras.